# Error tratando de realizar "signingReport" para obtener SHA-1 / SHA-256

Tags: android-studio, sha1, sha256

Al tratar de obtener el reporte de firma usando la terminal de Android Studio,

```
 C:\Users\jorgesys\git\AppHackster> ./gradlew signingReport
```

obtengo el error:

> FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
>
> - Where: Build file 'C:\Users\jorgesys\git\AppHackster\build.gradle' line: 2
> - What went wrong: An exception occurred applying plugin request [id: 'com.android.library']
>
> > Failed to apply plugin 'com.android.internal.library'.
> > Android Gradle plugin requires Java 11 to run. You are currently using Java 1.8.
> > You can try some of the following options:
> > - changing the IDE settings.
> > - changing the JAVA_HOME environment variable.
> > - changing `org.gradle.java.home` in `gradle.properties`.

El error indica el plugin 'com.android.library' en el archivo `build.gradle`:

```
plugins {
    id 'com.android.library'
    ...
}
...
...
```

Indica que debo usar Java 11, aunque el proyecto está configurado con esta versión de Java y además se encuentra definida la ruta en las variables de ambiente de mi pc.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

En el sitio en inglés existe una pregunta similar pero ninguna solución funciona:

[An exception occurred applying plugin request [id: 'com.android.application'] while integration Jetpack Compose](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66376361/an-exception-occurred-applying-plugin-request-id-com-android-application-wh)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Debido a la actualización de Gradle a 7.0+, una de las opciones indicadas por Android Studio es

> - changing `org.gradle.java.home` in `gradle.properties`.

Al **agregar la ruta en mi archivo `gradle.properties`**:

```
org.gradle.java.home=C\:\\Program Files\\Android\\Android Studio\\jre
```

y ejecutar el comando en la terminal:

```
./gradlew signingReport
```

Finalmente obtengo los valores requeridos:

```
Variant: debugAndroidTest
Config: debug
Store: C:\Users\jorgesys\.android\debug.keystore
Alias: AndroidDebugKey
MD5: 12:DA:14:D5:87:CE:C8:CC:8D:50:5D:CB:0E:D7:0B:AB
SHA1: 56:12:1F:75:26:E6:E2:D7:25:85:80:70:97:79:0A:AB:78:F7:51:7B
SHA-256: E5:57:15:B7:5E:74:07:ED:79:AF:5E:B6:4B:9D:3E:FA:90:8C:67:CF:6C:A8:53:79:54:02:98:22:6B:3A:3A:1F
Valid until: Wednesday, September 11, 2092
----------
```