Bug con google_sign_in_ en flutter 3.5
Me pueden ayudar con este problema en flutter, tengo dos bug con el mismo mensaje que dice:
The supplied phased action failed with an exception.
Could not create task ':google_sign_in_android:compileDebugUnitTestSources'.
this and base files have different roots: D:\Elmarcinho\Flutter 
FONE\TuTiendita\cliente_update_tutiendita\build\google_sign_in_android and 
C:\Users\dell\AppData\Local\Pub\Cache\hosted\pub.dev\google_sign_in_android-6.1.28\android.

Busque problema similares para poder solucionar pero todo lo que hice sin exito, actualice Android Studio Koala | 2024.1.1 Patch 2, cambie de version a kotilin use hasta la 1.9.22, cambie tambien la version del gradle probe con la 8.7, tambien use los comando flutter clean, flutter upgrade, flutter pub get, flutter pub cache clean, flutter pub cache repair
el problema no afecta en el funcionamiento de la app en MODO DEBUG, pero veo muchos mensaje al generar el RELEASE.APK y despues de usar el release.apk en un dispositivo movil veo que NO que esta funcionando google_sign_in correctamente (porque despues de dar clic en el boton de iniciar sesión con google abre a la pantalla donde se elige el email para iniciar sesión despues de seleccionar se cierra la pantalla y no hace nada no ingresa)
tengo generada la llave Sha-1 en mi proyecto y en Firebase y tambien el permiso de internet en el archivo AndroidManifest, cualquier ayuda le agradezco por su tiempo.

Future<UserCredential> signInWithGoogle() async{

  final GoogleSignInAccount? googleUser = await GoogleSignIn().signIn();

  final GoogleSignInAuthentication? googleAuth = await googleUser?.authentication;

  final credential = GoogleAuthProvider.credential(
    accessToken: googleAuth?.accessToken,
    idToken: googleAuth?.idToken,
  );

  return await FirebaseAuth.instance.signInWithCredential(credential);

}

Estoy usando Flutter 3.5
environment:
  sdk: ^3.5.1
dependencies:
  animate_do: ^3.3.4
  badges: ^3.1.2
  cloud_firestore: ^5.0.0
  country_code_picker: ^3.0.0
  curved_navigation_bar: ^1.0.6
  equatable: ^2.0.5
  firebase_auth: ^5.1.2
  firebase_core: ^3.0.0
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter
  flutter_bloc: ^8.1.5
  flutter_localizations:
    sdk: flutter
  flutter_native_splash: ^2.4.0
  flutter_spinkit: ^5.2.1
  font_awesome_flutter: ^10.7.0
  formz: ^0.7.0
  google_fonts: ^6.2.1
  google_sign_in: ^6.2.1

Archivo build.gradle
plugins {
id "com.android.application"
id 'com.google.gms.google-services'
id "kotlin-android"
id "dev.flutter.flutter-gradle-plugin"
}

def keystoreProperties = new Properties()
def keystorePropertiesFile = rootProject.file('key.properties')
if (keystorePropertiesFile.exists()) {
  keystoreProperties.load(new FileInputStream(keystorePropertiesFile))
}

android {
  namespace = "com.evem.cliente_tutiendita"
  compileSdk = flutter.compileSdkVersion
  ndkVersion = flutter.ndkVersion

compileOptions {
    sourceCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    targetCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
}

kotlinOptions {
    jvmTarget = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
}

defaultConfig {
    // TODO: Specify your own unique Application ID (https://developer.android.com/studio/build/application-id.html).
    applicationId = "com.evem.cliente_tutiendita"
    // You can update the following values to match your application needs.
    // For more information, see: https://flutter.dev/to/review-gradle-config.
    minSdk = 23
    targetSdk = flutter.targetSdkVersion
    versionCode = flutter.versionCode
    versionName = flutter.versionName
}

signingConfigs {
    release {
        keyAlias = keystoreProperties['keyAlias']
        keyPassword = keystoreProperties['keyPassword']
        storeFile = keystoreProperties['storeFile'] ? file(keystoreProperties['storeFile']) : null
        storePassword = keystoreProperties['storePassword']
    }
}

buildTypes {
    release {
        // TODO: Add your own signing config for the release build.
        // Signing with the debug keys for now, so `flutter run --release` works.
        signingConfig = signingConfigs.release
    }
 }
}

flutter {
 source = "../.."
}

Archivo settings.gradle
pluginManagement {
def flutterSdkPath = {
    def properties = new Properties()
    file("local.properties").withInputStream { properties.load(it) }
    def flutterSdkPath = properties.getProperty("flutter.sdk")
    assert flutterSdkPath != null, "flutter.sdk not set in local.properties"
    return flutterSdkPath
}()

includeBuild("$flutterSdkPath/packages/flutter_tools/gradle")

repositories {
    google()
    mavenCentral()
    gradlePluginPortal()
 }
}

plugins {
  id "dev.flutter.flutter-plugin-loader" version "1.0.0"
  id "com.android.application" version "7.3.0" apply false
  id "com.google.gms.google-services" version "4.3.15" apply false
  id "org.jetbrains.kotlin.android" version "1.8.10" apply false
}

include ":app"


Encontre solución al problema con google_sign_in en release.apk, no agregue el Sha-1 de producción en Firebase y solo tenia agregado el Sha-1 de desarrollo ese era el problema, una vez agregado el sha-1 de producción se soluciono, aqui dejo el enlace para generar los sha-1 para producción y desarrollo:  https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/589795/error-tratando-de-realizar-signingreport-para-obtener-sha-1-sha-256
